# Variance of a stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

**Problem**

Consider the classical brownian $W_t$, such as $var\left(W_t-W_u\right)=\left|t-u\right|$.

Consider the process defined by

$$X(t)=e^{-t/\tau}\left(X_0+\sqrt{Q_B}\int_0^t e^{u/\tau}dW_u\right)$$

With $Q_B$ being a real positive scaling constant.

I want to study
$$Y(t,L)=\frac{X(t+L)-X(t)}{L}={\left(e^{-L/\tau}-1\right)X(t)+e^{-L/\tau}\sqrt{Q_B}\int_{t}^{t+L} e^{(u-t)/\tau}dW_u \over L}$$
Ideally for any $t$, and at least for $t\to\infty$. (I'll refer to $\lim_{t\to\infty}Y(t,L)$ as $Y_\infty(L)$ from now on).

Since $Y(t,L)$ is gaussian, with mean ${\left(e^{-L/\tau}-1\right)e^{-t/\tau} \over L}X_0$, we just have to compute its variance.

---

**First approach**

Considering that the two terms of the sum are independant (do you agree that $\int_0^t e^{u/\tau}dW_u$ and $\int_{t}^{t+L} e^{(u-t)/\tau}dW_u$ are independant ?), I simply sum the variances and get
$$var\left(Y(t,L)\right)={\left(e^{-L/\tau}-1\right)^2var(X(t))+\left(1-e^{-2L/\tau}\right)\frac{Q_B\tau}{2} \over L^2}$$

Computing $var(X(t))$ :

- I can either calculate directly
  $$var(X(t))=Q_Be^{-2t/\tau}\int_0^t e^{2u/\tau}du=\frac{Q_B\tau}{2}\left(1-e^{-2t/\tau}\right)$$
- or, at least for $t\to \infty$, use the Laplace transform $\frac{1}{1+\tau s}$ and compute
  $$Q_B\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left|\frac{1}{1+2i\pi\tau f}\right|^2df=Q_B\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+4\pi^2\tau^2 f^2}df=\frac{Q_B}{2\tau}$$

First remark : when $t\to\infty$, the first converges to $\frac{Q_B\tau}{2}$, **so the two methods don't match. I guess the second one is incorrect, but why ?**

Considering $var(X(t))=\frac{Q_B\tau}{2}\left(1-e^{-2t/\tau}\right)$ (first result), we would get

$$var\left(Y(t,L)\right)=\left[\left(e^{-L/\tau}-1\right)^2\left(1-e^{-2t/\tau}\right)+\left(1-e^{-2L/\tau}\right)\right]\frac{Q_B\tau}{2L^2}$$

and

$$var\left(Y_\infty(L)\right)=\frac{Q_B\tau}{L^2}\left(1-e^{-L/\tau}\right)$$

**First, is this right ?**

---

**Second approach**

Another way to compute $var\left(Y_{\infty}(L)\right)$ would be to consider the Laplace transform
$$\frac{Y}{X}=\frac{e^{sL}-1}{L}$$
and evaluate
$$var\left(Y_{\infty}(L)\right)=Q_B\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left|\frac{e^{2i \pi Lf}-1}{L(1+2i\pi\tau f)}\right|^2df=Q_B\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{4sin^2\pi Lf}{L^2(1+4\pi^2\tau^2 f^2)}df$$
Let $x=\pi L f$, and we get
$$var\left(Y_{\infty}(L)\right)=\frac{4Q_B}{\pi L}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{sin^2x}{L^2+4\tau^2 x^2}dx$$
Since [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20sin(x)%5E2%2F(L%5E2%2B4*tau%5E2*x%5E2)%20dx%20from%20-infty%20to%20%2Binfty%20with%20L%3E0) gives us

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{sin^2x}{L^2+4\tau^2 x^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{4\tau L}(1-e^{-L/\tau})$$

we conclude

$$var\left(Y_{\infty}(L)\right)=\frac{Q_B}{\tau L^2}(1-e^{-L/\tau})$$

---

**Now, this differs from what we got in the first approach. Which one is right (if at least one is right...) ? And why is the other (or both) wrong ?**

Comment: In standard brownian motion $$VAr(W_{t+\Delta t}-W_t)=\Delta t$$ .now ,I think you must give a definition for $Q_B $  and , the first relation !

Comment: Yes, $Q_B$ is just a scaling constant. I actually have just edited the op to put the scaling in the definition of the $X$ process instead of in $W_t$, so as to use the most standard brownian possible.

Comment: Why not apply the trivial $$\mathrm{var}\left(\int g(u)dW_u\right)=\int g(u)^2du\ ?$$

Comment: That's what I did to get the first equality in the first approach, didn't I ? (Maybe I am missing something ?)

Comment: Also, even though I am clearly interested in the right answer, I also want to know what is wrong with the other calculus so as to understand where is the error.

Comment: The point is that this identity makes the whole Laplace stuff moot. (Unrelated: Please use @, that is, if you want your comments to be pinged.)

Comment: Side remark: $Y(t,L)$ is not Gaussian unless $X_0$ is Gaussian or degenerate.

Comment: @Did : I used the formula for the second member of the sum but not the first. Edited the op to use it also for the first member, showing the discrepancy in results. Apparently this is where the problem lies : the Laplace calculation doesn't give the same result. Isn't it supposed to, though ? (and thanks for the "@" tip :))

Comment: @Calculon : we can consider $X_0$ a simple scalar.

Comment: @Did : also, thanks to you, the problem as been pinpointed : I can't manage to reconcile the variance calculation through Ito's isometry with the variance calculation through integration of the PSD. In light of this, should I edit everything out to ask about only this, or should I rather start a new specific question ?

Comment: Found the problem, it seems it was simply me not being able to correctly solve my Laplace transform (shame on me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this was me being stupid and making a mistake in my solving of the system I was studying.

The integral expression of $X(t)$ was missing a $\frac{1}{\tau}$, and should have been like this :

$$X(t)=e^{-t/\tau}\left(X_0+\frac{\sqrt{Q_B}}{\tau}\int_0^t e^{u/\tau}dW_u\right)$$

Which in turn gives

$$Y(t,L)=\frac{X(t+L)-X(t)}{L}={\left(e^{-L/\tau}-1\right)X(t)+e^{-L/\tau}\frac{\sqrt{Q_B}}{\tau}\int_{t}^{t+L} e^{(u-t)/\tau}dW_u \over L}$$

and Ito's isometry now returns

$$var(X(t))=\frac{Q_B}{2\tau}\left(1-e^{-2t/\tau}\right)$$

and there is no discrepancy anymore with the integration of the PSD I was doing in parallel. Thus we also get

$$var\left(Y(t,L)\right)=\left[\left(e^{-L/\tau}-1\right)^2\left(1-e^{-2t/\tau}\right)+\left(1-e^{-2L/\tau}\right)\right]\frac{Q_B}{2\tau L^2}$$

and finally, we do get

$$var\left(Y_{\infty}(L)\right)=\frac{Q_B}{\tau L^2}(1-e^{-L/\tau})$$

Which also matches the result obtained through direct integration of the PSD, and all's right with the world again.

Sorry everyone for the trouble !